# Yii2 - register js file after active form assets

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

Is it possible to put js file after active form assets, when the file added via **registerJsFile**?

I have this code, but the file will be added after **yii.js**, but before **yii.activeForm.js**, and I can't find the right call at the moment:

```
$this->registerJsFile('@web/js/address.js', [
        'depends'  => [\yii\web\YiiAsset::className()]
]);
```

Comment: added an answer se if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **`yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset`** which you need to add the dependency to.

You need to add the dependency in the following way

```
$this->registerJsFile('js/buy-now.js', [
    'depends' => [yii\widgets\ActiveFormAsset::className()],
]);
```

you can always check the source code for any specific widget class to see the name of the assets file that it is using inside the **`registerClientScript()`**.

See [**`ActiveForm`**](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/ActiveForm.php)
source

Comment: You saved me once again :). I tried several other paths (web, bootstrap...), but didn't go in the widgets directions. Thanks once again :)